# Is it possible to return two separate values to a function in this case?

Tags: c

I am trying to **determine the minimum number that a user enters into a text file and also the position at which this is found**

**Attempt at Solution :** I have tried the following code to implement `minIndex` as part of a function which is returning the minimum value correctly :

```
int minimum(int number, int *minIndex) {

static int minNumber = INT_MAX;
static int index = 0;

if (number < minNumber) {
    minNumber = number;
    *minIndex = index;
}
index++;
return minNumber;
}
```

**EDIT** I am then implementing later on:

```
    int minNumber = 0;
    int finished = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;
    int in = 0;

    for (int i = 1; !finished; i++)
{
    if (fscanf(fp, "%s", word) < 1)
        finished = 1;
    else {
        number = atoi(word);
        minNumber = minimum(number, &in);
        printf("\nstring  is \t %s\n", word);
        printf("integer is \t %d\n", number);
    }
}
printf("min number is %d at position %d\n", minNumber,in);
```

The minimum number is returned correctly, however `minIndex` is always shown to be 1.

Is there a problem with my function or is there a more basic issue at hand which I am missing?

Comment: @Yuriy Ivaskevych I think you had a very good point regarding this matter earlier.

Comment: any reason why `minNumber` and `index` are static?

Comment: Your code is checking one number to see if it is less than INT_MAX (which it probably is).  There is no looping or arrays or anything, so I don't know how you expect to find an "index".

Comment: [tested](http://ideone.com/VET3dY) (gives correct result) maybe something is missing? Btw, @StoryTeller provided another great approach

Comment: @hymie , check the edit. For example, the user is entering up to 10 numbers.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych, hmm still returing a value of 1. It seems like I am missing something. Thanks for testing this to confirm it works.

Comment: @Rizzo Then maybe edit your question and provide more code.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych, I have made some adjustments.

Comment: @Rizzo It's ok) you're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return two values, you need to return a `struct`. And I would suggest to just use it entirely to hold the state of your computation instead of the statics.

```
struct minimum_state {
  int minNumber;
  int minIndex;
  int index;
};

#define MINIMUM_STATE_INIT_VAL \
{ .minNumber = INT_MAX, .minIndex = -1, .index = 0 }

void minimum(int number, struct minimum_state *p_state) {

  if (number < p_state->minNumber) {
    p_state->minNumber = number;
    p_state->minIndex = p_state->index;
  }
  ++(p_state->index);

}
```

Then your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
struct minimum_state = MINIMUM_STATE_INIT_VAL;
while(next_number_exists()) {
  minimum(next_number(), &minimum_state);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this matter. We have not covered structs yet however I will be researching and reading on this further. Is there any other way, however, to do this without structs ?

Comment: @Rizzo - You can pass an array into the function for it to fill... but it's less readable.

Comment: @Rizzo - Whatever works for you. Output parameters are also a viable option (which I completely forgot, for shame). Just remember the `struct` example when you design more complex software. Data that belongs together should be in the same data structure.

Answer (score 1):

A function does only return 1 type. Make it a structure and put your 2 integers in it.
Or return 1 element and handle one as pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, what I would do is to have two functions (single responsability principle).

Then, use your index function and if you want the value, use array[minIndexValue]

So go for option 1, and if you want the minValue, don't call your function, just access to it by it's index

In your case, your code is returning always 1 because it seems that you're iterating all your numbers outside this function, so your index at this function is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I guess that might be an alternative and maybe simpler approach, however I was hoping that my attempt at the solution to be a guide as to which option I was leaning to.

Comment: @Rizzo Check my edit. Show us how you're calling this function. In your code, the index wil be always 1 cause you're setting it to 0 and doing ++ INSIDE this function, and it seems that you're iterating through your set of integerser OUTSIDE this function.